# How to use multiple files in DataProviderInput while automating API test cases

Tags: automation

We are automating API test cases in our project.

We have API request/response test cases wherein we provide the json request file as part of the DataProviderInput.

@Test(dataProvider = "renderFormSetDataProvider", dataProviderClass = EtqRenderFormSetDataProvider.class)
@DataProviderInput(filePath = "src/test/resources/testdata/usecase/RenderFormSetCICOnboardingFallback.json")

Can we provide multiple files as input here for example if we want to loop through them for a single usecase?

Right now it works fine for 1 file, but I want 2 files to be ran in succession for the same code.